# SQL server how to change pipe separated column string to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2014

I have 3 columns in a table, in which 2 columns have string separated by a '|' pipe. Both these columns values depend on each other.

For an example: I have data in the table like this :

```
ID  product quantity
1   A|B|C   1|2|3
2   X|Y|Z   7|8|9
```

I would like to change it to something like this :

```
ID  product quantity
1   A   1
1   B   2
1   C   3
2   X   7
2   Y   8
2   Z   9
```

As i am working with SSMS, i don't have any other choice except SQL. I try to use cross apply but i am not getting right result. For 1 row i receive 9 rows instead of getting 3. 
could anyone suggest me which method should i use?

Thank you in advance!!
JACK

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Quite near what i want but there is a problem with this. i don't have unique id in the table. So for an example if i have same id 8 times and every id contains 4 product and 4 quantity. I should receive 32 products but i am receiving 256 products. Could you tell me what should i change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ID INT,  product VARCHAR(100) , quantity VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
(1   ,'A|B|C' ,  '1|2|3'),
(2   ,'X|Y|Z' ,  '7|8|9');
```

**Query**

```
WITH Products AS (
        SELECT    ID
                , Product_Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Products
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
        FROM (
              SELECT  ID
                     ,Cast ('<X>' 
                           + Replace(product, '|', '</X><X>') 
                           + '</X>' AS XML) AS Product_Data
                FROM #t
            ) AS t 
        CROSS APPLY Product_Data.nodes ('/X') AS Product_Split(a) 
),
 Quantities AS (
        SELECT    ID
                , Quantity_Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Quantity
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
        FROM (
                SELECT  ID
                        ,Cast ('<X>' 
                            + Replace(quantity, '|', '</X><X>') 
                            + '</X>' AS XML) AS Quantity_Data
                FROM #t
            ) AS t 
        CROSS APPLY Quantity_Data.nodes ('/X') AS Quantity_Split(a)
 )
 SELECT   t.ID
        , P.Products
        , Q.Quantity

 FROM #t t
 LEFT JOIN Products     P   ON t.ID = p.ID
 LEFT JOIN Quantities   Q   ON Q.ID = t.ID 
                            AND Q.rn = p.rn
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ Products ║ Quantity ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ A        ║        1 ║
║  1 ║ B        ║        2 ║
║  1 ║ C        ║        3 ║
║  2 ║ X        ║        7 ║
║  2 ║ Y        ║        8 ║
║  2 ║ Z        ║        9 ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Quite near what i want but there is a problem with this. i don't have unique id in the table. So for an example if i have same id 8 times and every id contains 4 product and 4 quantity. I should receive 32 products but i am receiving 256 products. Could you tell me what should i change

Answer (score 2):

This is rather tricky, because you need for the values to match up.  The following takes a recursive CTE approach:

```
with cte as (
      select id,
             left(product, charindex('|', product + '|') - 1) as product,
             left(quantity, charindex('|', quantity + '|') - 1) as quantity,
             substring(product, charindex('|', product + '|') + 1, 1000) as products,
             substring(quantity, charindex('|', quantity + '|') + 1, 1000) as quantities
     from t
     union all
      select id,
             left(products, charindex('|', products + '|') - 1) as product,
             left(quantities, charindex('|', quantities + '|') - 1) as quantity,
             substring(products, charindex('|', products + '|') + 1, 1000) as products,
             substring(quantities, charindex('|', quantities + '|') + 1, 1000) as quantities
     from cte
     where products <> '' and quantities <> ''
    )
select id, product, quantity
from cte;
```

Here is a little [Rextester](http://rextester.com/HDNMV61103).

Comment: It's a good approach... You might add a counter to the recursive part in order to get the elements back into the previous sort order (if order matters...)

Comment: I also tried this approach but i only receive values for first product which is also total id multiply by 2 and i don't receive anything for any other product. I don't have unique id in my table.

Comment: @user3423920 . . . Have you looked at the rextester link?  This code actually works.

Answer (score 0):

splitting strings is easy, there are tons of examples. The tricky part here is to connect the fragments via their position. My suggestion uses XMLs abilities to  target an element by its position:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,  product VARCHAR(100) , quantity VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 (1   ,'A|B|C' ,  '1|2|3')
,(2   ,'X|Y|Z' ,  '7|8|9');
```

--This is the query

```sql
WITH CastedToXML AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(product,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS ProductXml
         ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(quantity,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS QuantityXml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
      ,ProductXml.value('/x[sql:column("Nmbr")][1]','nvarchar(10)') AS ProductAtPosition
      ,QuantityXml.value('/x[sql:column("Nmbr")][1]','int') AS QuantityAtPosition
FROM CastedToXML
--Create a set of running numbers (spt_values is just a pre-filled table with many rows)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(CastedToXML.ProductXml.value('count(/x)','int')) 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
             FROM master..spt_values) AS Tally(Nmbr);
```

the result

```
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| ID | Nmbr | ProductAtPosition | QuantityAtPosition |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 1    | A                 | 1                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 2    | B                 | 2                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 3    | C                 | 3                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | 1    | X                 | 7                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | 2    | Y                 | 8                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | 3    | Z                 | 9                  |
+----+------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Some explanation:

the cast to xml transfers your `A|B|C` to

```
<x>A</x>
<x>B</x>
<x>C</x>
```

This list is joined with a number set created *on the fly* using the count of `<x>` as the `TOP` limit.

Now it is easy to pick the `<x>` out of your XML by the position.

Try it out!

### UPDATE: Non-unique IDs

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,  product VARCHAR(100) , quantity VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 (1   ,'A|B|C' ,  '1|2|3')
,(2   ,'X|Y|Z' ,  '7|8|9')
,(3   ,'a|b|c' ,  '7|8|9')
,(2   ,'D|e|f' ,  '7|8|9')
;
--This is the query

WITH CastedToXML AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowIndex
         ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(product,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS ProductXml
         ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(quantity,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS QuantityXml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
      ,ProductXml.value('/x[sql:column("Nmbr")][1]','nvarchar(10)') AS ProductAtPosition
      ,QuantityXml.value('/x[sql:column("Nmbr")][1]','int') AS QuantityAtPosition
FROM CastedToXML
--Create a set of running numbers (spt_values is just a pre-filled table with many rows)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(CastedToXML.ProductXml.value('count(/x)','int')) 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
             FROM master..spt_values) AS Tally(Nmbr);
```

Comment: the problem is i don't have distinct id. I have so many values with the same id, where this approach is not working. i am receiving 16 values instead of 8 if i have (1   ,'A|B|C' ,  '1|2|3')
,(1   ,'X|Y|Z' ,  '7|8|9');

Comment: @user3423920 easy to solve: either add an identity column or add a running number on the fly with `row_numer() over(partition by ID order by ID) as RowIndex` . Add this to the first select

Comment: @user3423920 cannot test this at the moment... I doubt your observations... This is computed row-wise. Does your query include any other Join?

Comment: @user3423920 I just tested this and your observation is not true. This returns exactly as described even with non-unique IDs. The mentioned addition with `ROW_NUMBER()` works too. See my update